# Finding Acronyms Using Regex In Python

Tags: python, regex, acronym

I'm trying to use regex in Python to match acronyms separated by periods. I have the following code:

```
import re
test_string = "U.S.A."
pattern = r'([A-Z]\.)+'
print re.findall(pattern, test_string)
```

The result of this is:

```
['A.']
```

I'm confused as to why this is the result. I know + is greedy, but why is are the first occurrences of [A-Z]\. ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(...)` in regex creates a group. I suggest changing to:

```
pattern = r'(?:[A-Z]\.)+'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I looked more into 'groups' with Python's regex. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 5):

## Description

This regex will:

- capture all the acronyms like `U.S.A.` in a sentence
- avoids matching uppercase words at the end of a sentence

`(?:(?<=\.|\s)[A-Z]\.)+`

[image]

## Example

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/9bslFxvfzQ

**Sample Text**

```
This is the U.S.A. we have RADAR.
```

**Matches**

```
U.S.A
```