# Extract acronyms patterns from string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this problem:

```
list_= ["blabla S.P.A words J.R words. , words","words words !! words s.r.l words. D.T. words","words words I.B.M. words words."]
```

I would like to have:

```
['S.P.A', 'J.R']
['s.r.l', 'D.T.']
['I.B.M.']
```

I found this amazing solution [Finding Acronyms Using Regex In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779771/finding-acronyms-using-regex-in-python) that returns:

```
['S.P.', 'J.']
['s.r.', 'D.T.']
['I.B.M.']
```

How can I use that solution in my situation?

Thank you

Comment: what about `(?<= )(\w+\.[^ ]+)` ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make the final period optional. Also lookbehind for a space or the start of the string before the first letter to ensure it's not part of another word, and lookahead after the end for a space or the end of the string:

```
pattern = r'(?i)(?:^|(?<= ))(?:[a-z]\.)+[a-z]\.?(?= |$)'
```

Comment: OP didn't have any digits in his input, but if there are, just change the `\w`s to `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: but you know what acronyms are letters, better to make them letters. +1

Comment: it's also extracting `A.B.C` from `AAA.B.C`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre oh that is great how spot it.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod That's what the `(?i)` is for, figured it'd be nicer than repeating `[a-zA-z]` twice

Comment: thank you for your answer!

I tried this code on this case "A.TT.L", I do not know if it is an acronym (I hope not, because I think I do not want it :) ) 

In this case returns "A.T"

Comment: @frquestions Add lookahead after the end for a space or the end of the string `(?= |$)`

Comment: also tell OP to use `flags=re.I` or your pattern won't match uppercased letters.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's what the `(?i)` is for

Comment: there is still a small bug: A.TT.L => A.TTL

Comment: @frquestions I don't think those count because there's more than one letter in between. If you *want* to allow more than one letter in between, use `[a-z]+` instead of `[a-z]`.