# Regex to extract acronyms

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am using regex to extract acronyms(only specific types) from text in python.

- ABC (all caps within round brackets or square brackets or between word endings)
- A.B.C (same as above but having only one '.' in between)
- A&B&C (same as above but having only one '&' in between)

So far I am using

```
text = "My name is STEVE. My friend works at (I.A.). Indian Army(IA). B&W also B&&W Also I...A"
re.findall('\\b[A-Z][A-Z.&]{2,7}\\b', text)

Output is : ['STEVE', 'I.A', 'B&W', 'B&&W', 'I...A']
I want to exclude B&&W and I..A, but include (IA).
```

I am aware of the below links but I am unable to use them correctly. Kindly help.

[Extract acronyms patterns from string using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659009/extract-acronyms-patterns-from-string-using-regex)

[Finding Acronyms Using Regex In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779771/finding-acronyms-using-regex-in-python)

[RegEx to match acronyms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076016/regex-to-match-acronyms)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there must be only a `&`, or a `.` or empty string between the uppercase letters and they can appear inconsistently (as in this fake `NA&T.O` string), you can use

```
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z](?:[&.]?[A-Z])+\b', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1SJoe/16). It matches a whole word that starts with a single uppercase letter and then has one or more sequences of an optional `&` or `.` followed with another uppercase letter.

Here, I would suggest

```py
[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'\b[A-Z](?=([&.]?))(?:\1[A-Z])+\b', text)]
```

Or, if you
See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1SJoe/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `(?=([&.]?))` - a positive lookahead that contains a capturing group that captures into  Group 1 an optional `&` or `.` char
- `(?:\1[A-Z])+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\1` - same char captured into Group 1 (so, you won't get `A.T&W`)
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `\b` - word boundary.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/0n6E8x):

```
import re
rx = r"\b[A-Z](?=([&.]?))(?:\1[A-Z])+\b"
s = "My name is STEVE. My friend works at (I.A.). Indian Army(IA). B&W also B&&W Also I...A"
print( [x.group() for x in re.finditer(rx, s)] )
# => ['STEVE', 'I.A', 'IA', 'B&W']
```

Answer (score 9):

What you want is a capital followed by a bunch of capitals, with optional dots or ampersands in between.

```
re.findall('\\b[A-Z](?:[\\.&]?[A-Z]){1,7}\\b', text)
```

Breaking it down:

- All back slashes are doubled because they need escaping
- `\b` word border
- `[A-Z]` capital
- `(?:` opening a non-capturing group
- `[\.&]` character class containing `.` and `&`
- `?` optional
- `[A-Z]` followed by another capital
- `)` closing non-capturing group of an optional `.` or `&`, followed by a capital
- `{1,7}` repeating that group 1 - 7 times
- `\b` word border

We want a non-capturing group since `re.findall` returns groups (if present).

There are better ways of matching capitals that work across all of the Unicode characters.

This *does* match `B&WW` and `B&W.W`, since we do not enforce the use of the (same) character every time. If you want that, the expression gets a bit more complex (though not much).

Comment: Hi @SQB it just catches the E from 'STEVE' and A from 'Army(IA)'. I think its just catching the last characters of matches within length {1, 7}
`Output - [('E', ''), ('A', '')] `

Comment: Ah, of course. The grouping is interfering. `re.findall` returns groups if present, so I changed the group to non-capturing. I also changed another group to a character class as it should've been in the first place.

Comment: This look good. Thanks @SQB Just to clarify the **?:** in `(?:[` is for non-grouping and **?** in `&]?[A` is for 0 or 1 matches. Am I correct?? Could you also suggest some good references to master regex..